# how to fix product detail html layout issue in magento

Tags: html, magento

i am unable to find layout issue

issue is some of my product detail pages layout are not working fine, product is not updated and also it is not possible to update all the product please let me know how to fix it

image of issue attached below
[please click to see product page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzqqK.png)

As my 3rd column merges in 2nd column

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Magento admin question and belongs over on magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

modify your css files to improve layout issues. 
also i didnt understand what exactly you are trying to say about product updates.
plz provide Detail info .

Comment: my product detail page has 3 colum but it give 2 column and merge third one in second column and when i updated it in from admin it is not updated it .  and issue appeared in short description column it gives </li></li wen i deleted it and update it it will not updated that and remain </li></li

Comment: plz upload picture of your product detail page.